# ggplot2 x-axis with date goes too far

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to generate a very basic plot containing two lines which connect monthly values from June, July and August.

Here is some code for an reproducible example:

```
# create the vectors
MODEL <- c(78, 47, 101)
CONTROL <- c(80, 46, 100)
Date <- seq(from= as.Date("2003-06-01"), to = as.Date("2003-08-31"), by = "month")

# combine the vectors to a data frame
my.df <- data.frame(MODEL, CONTROL, Date)

# give colnames
colnames(my.df) <- c("MODEL", "CONTROL", "Month")

# plot
ggplot(my.df, aes(x= Month)) +
  geom_line(aes(y= MODEL), color= "blue", size= 1) +
  geom_line(aes(y= CONTROL), color= "red", size= 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits= c(40, 110), breaks = seq(40,110,10)) +
  scale_x_date(limit=c(as.Date("2003-06-01"),as.Date("2003-08-31")), date_breaks= "1 month", date_labels = "%b") +
  ylab("CIMFD [kg/m²]") + xlab("") +
  theme_bw() + theme(text= element_text(size= 20)) +
  theme(axis.text= element_text(size= 25, color= "black")) +
  theme(legend.position= "none", legend.spacing.x= unit(1, "cm"))
```

The code leads to the following plot:
[image]

The problem is obvious: the x-axis also displays "Sept", even though the data frame does not contain any data that goes beyond August.
Anybody with a hint how to make the x-axis stop directly after "Aug"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Current `scale_x_date()` function has a limit argument that stretches up to the end of August, which is why it's including September. To solve this issue, you can modify your limit to end at the beginning of August instead of the end.

```
# create the vectors
MODEL <- c(78, 47, 101)
CONTROL <- c(80, 46, 100)
Date <- seq(from= as.Date("2003-06-01"), to = as.Date("2003-08-01"), by = "month")

# combine the vectors to a data frame
my.df <- data.frame(MODEL, CONTROL, Date)

# give colnames
colnames(my.df) <- c("MODEL", "CONTROL", "Month")

# plot
ggplot(my.df, aes(x= Month)) +
  geom_line(aes(y= MODEL), color= "blue", size= 1) +
  geom_line(aes(y= CONTROL), color= "red", size= 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits= c(40, 110), breaks = seq(40,110,10)) +
  scale_x_date(limit=c(as.Date("2003-06-01"),as.Date("2003-08-01")), date_breaks= "1 month", date_labels = "%b") +
  ylab("CIMFD [kg/m²]") + xlab("") +
  theme_bw() + theme(text= element_text(size= 20)) +
  theme(axis.text= element_text(size= 25, color= "black")) +
  theme(legend.position= "none", legend.spacing.x= unit(1, "cm"))
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot Developer, so simple and yet so useful.

Answer (score 1):

To make the x-axis stop directly after "Aug" in your plot, you can set the expand argument of scale_x_date to include only the necessary range of dates. You can use the expand argument and specify the expansion for both the lower and upper ends of the axis. In this case, you want to keep the axis up to the last date in your dataset, which is August 31, 2003.
I think By setting expand = c(0, 0), the x-axis will only cover the range of dates from June to August without any extra padding. This should remove "Sept" from the x-axis. Now it should work as your plot will display only the data points for June, July, and August.